# PHP DateTime - set a start point for things like 'next wednesday' to go off

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the below method to calculate when the next time in a schedule of times is.

```
public static function getNextUtcTimestampFromSchedule($schedule, $timezone)
{
    $timestamps = array();
    foreach ($schedule as $day => $times){
        $dt = new \DateTime('next '.self::getDayString($day), new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        foreach ($times as $time){
            list($hour, $min) = explode(':', $time);
            $dt->setTime($hour, $min);
            $timestamps[] = $dt->getTimestamp();
        }
    }
    sort($timestamps);
    return $timestamps[0];
}
```

`$schedule` is an array, like this:

```
$schedule = array(
    0 => array('11:00', '17:00'), 
    1 => array('10:00', '18:00'),
    2 => array('09:00', '18:00'), 
    3 => array('11:00', '17:00'),
    4 => array('11:00', '16:00'),
    5 => array('15:00', '16:00'),
    6 => array('11:00', '12:00'),
);
```

`getDayString` simply converts, for example, 0 to 'sunday'.

In order to write unit tests, I need to spoof the time that `now()` is at, or pass it into the method and use it.

The question is, how can I use that with DateTime?

i.e. `DateTime('next wednesday')` needs to be told what time 'now' is, in order to figure out 'next wednesday' in a predictable way, so that it can be unit tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __construct function has an [optional param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php):

```
public __construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

An example:

```
<?php
try {
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Edit: You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to generate a timestamp, then use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to generate the string to pass to the new object:

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("next wednesday")));
```

Comment: But how would I use that in conjunction with the need to pass it 'next wednesday'? I'm already using that parameter.

Comment: @bcmcfc Have a peep at the edit. How would that fit your problem?

Comment: Ah, yes, that'll work when the spoofed timestamp is also passed into the strtotime call. Thanks.